# Swift array remove consecutive numbers via filter

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

How it is possible to write `filter` function that will remove consecutive numbers from array.

By consecutive I mean 1,2,3,4 form a *sequence* contrary to 1,3,5 (missing the 2 and 5).

Example:

```
let input = [1,2,3,4,8,10,12,19]
//Expected filter function.
let output = [8,10,12,19]
```

Comment: I would like flexible function that will remove consecutive. I think it is impossible to do with filter function

Comment: Ah, my bad, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Why is 1 excluded from the output?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk please consider clarifying in the question whether you want to **1)** _remove all numbers that are in a sequence of consecutive numbers_ (input `[1,2,3,4,8,10,12,19]` yields output `[8,10,12,19]`), or **2)** _remove all numbers that are in themselves consecutive w.r.t. the preceding number_ (input `[1,2,3,4,8,10,12,19]` yields `[1, 8,10,12,19]`, leaving `1` intact). The accepted (neat) answer provides a solution for **2)**, but your example `output` above provides the expected result from applying **1)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` which acts as a `map` and a `filter` against nil:

```
let output = input.enumerated().flatMap { index, element in
    return index > 0 && input[index - 1] + 1 == element ? nil : element
}

print(output) // [1, 8, 10, 12, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let input = [1,2,3,4,8,10,12,19]

func filterConsecutive(array: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    guard array.count > 1 else {
        return array
    }

    var result = [Int]()
    for i in 0...array.count-2 {
        let first = array[i]
        let second = array[i+1]
        if second != first + 1 {
            result.append(second)
        }
    }
    return result
}

let result = filterConsecutive(array: input)
```

Comment: if i have two numbers for example [1,2] thay are consecutive and it should return [] but not [1,2]

Comment: This won't work if the first number is greater than the second number, because `second - first` is not going to be greater than 1, but they are not consecutive numbers. The check should be `second != first + 1`

Comment: Note that this does not work as intended if the last sequence of numbers are consecutive, e.g. with `input = [1,2,3,4,8,10,12,18,19]`, the last numbers `18,19` will remain in the resulting array.